# É possivel mudar a cor de fundo de uma imagem em que essa imagem é toda branca em xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Eu tenho uma imagem que é branca por defeito, é possível mudar essa cor via código?

```
  Cor ImagemFundobackground = CriarCor(RecursosCores.preto);  
  ImagemFundo.BackgroundColor =
  UIColor.FromRGB(ImagemFundobackground.Red,
  ImagemFundobackground.Green,  ImagemFundobackground.Blue);
```

Sendo que **CriarCor** é uma função que trás a cor a partir dos recursos
**ImagemFundo** é uma elemento que é uma **UIImageView**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para o problema em questão como a imagem era apenas branca o que eu fiz foi tirar a imagem e atribuir uma cor:

```
  Cor ImagemFundobackground = CriarCor(RecursosCores.preto);  
  ImagemFundo.Image = null;
  ImagemFundo.BackgroundColor =
  UIColor.FromRGB(ImagemFundobackground.Red,
  ImagemFundobackground.Green,  ImagemFundobackground.Blue);
```